# How to access FDs in fd_set through indexing in Linux?

Tags: c++, c, linux, sockets, networking

For example, I can access them with `fd_set.fd_array[i]` in Windows..

```
request_list getIncomingRequests()
{
    fd_set master_set_copy = master_set;
    request_list requests;
    int socket_count = select(0, &master_set_copy, nullptr, nullptr, nullptr);
    for (int i = 0; i < socket_count; ++i)
    {
    #ifdef _WIN32
        auto req_fd = master_set_copy.fd_array[i];
    #else
        auto req_fd = master_set_copy...[i]; // ??
    #endif
        sockaddr_in req_addr;
        getsockname(req_fd, (sockaddr*)&req_addr, &addr_len);
        requests.push_back(request(req_fd, this->fd, req_addr));
    }
    return requests;
}
```

But `fd_array` doesn't exist in Linux so I need an equivalent.

Comment: C and C++ are two different languages. Please remove one of the tags.

Comment: can you edit head and tail of what you want to achieve ? it's too generic question for me,

Comment: @DYZ I know but the socket API is for both C and C++ and not for just of them.

Comment: @ThiruShetty I just want to access any socket in fd_set through indexing..

Comment: @ThiruShetty I edited the question to clearer one.

Comment: Since your call to `select` passes zero as the first parameter, it cannot possibly discover any sockets. Check the docs, "*nfds should be set to the highest-numbered file descriptor in any of the three sets, plus 1.*"

Comment: I would strongly suggest you just not use `select`. Probably your simplest option is to use `poll` instead. The `select` function has an awkward interface.

Comment: @DavidSchwartz My code works as it should in Windows and it retrieves any sockets.. It doesn't have any problem but I posted it whole just for clarification. All I need is to access fd_set's FDs if possible in Linux.. ty

Comment: @XStylish Networking code tends to be somewhat platform-specific and trying to take code specifically designed around one platform's quirks and get it to work on another platform without removing the quirks makes that second platform a second-class platform for the code. Windows really only supports `select` badly as a nod to compatibility with POSIX platforms, and those have even moved on.

Comment: @XStylish you can't directly use windows code directly.. need little modification as suggested by [DYZ](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53699058/3698648)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The POSIX implementation of `fd_set` does not require that the structure has the field `fd_array`. `fd_set` is supposed to be an opaque data structure.

You can check which file descriptors are set by iterating through all supported descriptors (`0` through `FD_SETSIZE-1`) and calling `FD_ISSET()`.

**Note** from the manual page:

> `select()` can monitor only file descriptors numbers that are less than `FD_SETSIZE`; `poll(2)` does not have this limitation.  See BUGS.

Comment: I also needed to set the first parameter in `select()` to `FD_SETSIZE`. It really weird that it worked in Windows without it but.. thank you.

Comment: If that's so, then I think I'll use `poll`.

Comment: Use `poll`. `select` is **awful**.

Comment: @XStylish sockets on Linux use descriptors, so `select()` needs to be told the highest descriptor to monitor. But sockets on Windows are kernel objects, and the first parameter of `select()` is ignored. This is documented behavior. Also, because `fd_set` is opaque, on some platforms you need to use `FD_COPY()` to copy one `fd_set` to another.

Answer (score 1):

Add a new variable, maybe `max_fd`, that tracks the highest numbered file descriptor in the set. Then you can do this:

```
request_list getIncomingRequests()
{
    fd_set master_set_copy = master_set;
    request_list requests;
    int socket_count = select(max_fd + 1, &master_set_copy, nullptr, nullptr, nullptr);
    for (int req_fd = 0; req_fd <= max_fd; ++req_fd)
    {
        if (!FD_ISSET(req_fd, &master_set_copy))
            continue;
        sockaddr_in req_addr;
        getsockname(req_fd, (sockaddr*)&req_addr, &addr_len);
        requests.push_back(request(req_fd, this->fd, req_addr));
    }
    return requests;
}
```

But you're probably better off using `poll` instead of `select`.